# disable block letters in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I change the result so that is shows only the first letter of the word in Uppercase and the rest in Lowercase

So it should be Texas Watch instead of Texas Watch.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ilg.png)

Code

SELECT title
FROM film

Comment: Try a web search for "oracle proper case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `INITCAP` function.

```
SQL> select initcap('LITTle foOt') result from dual;

RESULT
-----------
Little Foot

SQL>
```